# How do I loop a dictionary through another loop?

Tags: python, bots, discord.py, reddit, praw

I am currently making a loop that goes over each entry (subreddit and discord channel id) in a json file.

```
for subreddit_name, channel_id in available_streams.items():
            get_channel = guild.get_channel(channel_id)
            print(f"{subreddit_name}: #{get_channel}")
            subreddit = reddit.subreddit(subreddit_name)
            for submission in subreddit.stream.submissions():
                try:

                except Exception as e:
```

The first loop is working fine (shows all keys and values in the dictionary). However, when the `subreddit_name` goes to the next for loop, only the first item is being used, meaning only posts from one subreddit is being streamed. Is there something wrong in my code that makes it only consider the first entry?

Comment: Code ofnthe second for loop's bodybis missing. And the question asks for help with that part. Please add the missing code

Answer (score 1):

If you're using PRAW you shouldn't put a stream inside a loop.

subreddit.stream.submissions() will continue to stream indefinitely and the for loop will never roll over to the next item.

You should try a different method such as streaming asynchronously or only retrieving the last x posts from subreddit. Or you could even use break in the 2nd loop when your conditions are met.

```
for subreddit_name, channel_id in available_streams.items():
    get_channel = guild.get_channel(channel_id)
    print(f"{subreddit_name}: #{get_channel}")
    subreddit = reddit.subreddit(subreddit_name)
    for submission in subreddit.new(limit=10):
        try:
            print(submission.title)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Couldn't retrieve submission title '{submission}': {e}")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate through the keys and then assign the value inside the loop

```
outerDict = dict() # Assume there's more dicts in there like you want
for a in outerDict:
   element_value_inside_outerDict = outerDict.get(a)
   # Some code for whatever you want to do with it
   for b in element_value_inside_outerDict:
       value_inside_innerDict = element_value_inside_outerDict.get(b)
```

Maybe that'll fix it